# What is the format for an `INTERVAL` parameter in a `format()` call

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm updating an existing stored function, handling two additional parameters and inserting them, where required. Within the function, I `INSERT` a row into a table using a call to `EXECUTE format()`, something like this...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE function_p (
    p_name              TEXT        DEFAULT '',
    p_step              INT         DEFAULT NULL,
    p_project_duration  INTERVAL    DEFAULT '2W',
    )
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format('
    INSERT INTO table_2 (column_1, column_2, column_3, name, step)
        SELECT one_column, two_column, three_column, %L, %s
            FROM generate_series(now()::DATE, now()::DATE + %L, INTERVAL ''1 day'') d
            CROSS JOIN table_1',
    p_name, p_step, p_project_duration);   
END;
$$
```

I know this is a pretty rubbish example, but it's pseudo-code, ok?! ;)

In the `generate_series()` call...

- If I use format `%L` I get error **"operator is not unique: date + unknown"**
- If I use format `%I` I get error **"column "P14d" does not exist"**
- If I use format `%s` I get error **"column "P14d" does not exist"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass strings as parameters, use placeholders and pass the correct data types. Only use the `format()` placeholders for the identifiers, pass the actual parameters with the `using` clause of the `execute` command:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE function_p (
    p_name              TEXT        DEFAULT '',
    p_step              INT         DEFAULT NULL,
    p_project_duration  INTERVAL    DEFAULT '2W',
    )
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format('
    INSERT INTO table_2 (column_1, column_2, column_3, name, step)
    SELECT one_column, two_column, three_column, %L, %s
    FROM generate_series($1, $2, $3) d
      CROSS JOIN table_1', p_name, p_step)
    using current_date, current_date + p_project_duration, interval '1 day';
END;
$$
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems I've found a hack-fix/cludge/bodge, yay!

It works if I use the '`%s`' format and then cast it to `INTERVAL`.

```
            FROM generate_series(now()::DATE, now()::DATE + ''%s''::INTERVAL, INTERVAL ''1 day'') d
```